# How to prevent urlencoding of liquid tags?

Tags: r, r-markdown, pandoc

Building a post for a Jekyll site from an RMarkdown document and running into a problem with pandoc's "helpful" URL encoding of links. I hit the RStudio "Knit" button on this document:

````
---
output: md_document
---

```{r setup, include=FALSE}
knitr::opts_knit$set(base.url = '{{ site.baseurl }}/')
knitr::opts_chunk$set(fig.path = 'assets/images/')
```

```{r sin_plot}
plot(1:100, sin(1:100))
```
````

And I get this markdown document:

```
    plot(1:100, sin(1:100))

![](%7B%7B%20site.baseurl%20%7D%7D/assets/images/sin_plot-1.png)
```

What I need is this markdown document:

```
    plot(1:100, sin(1:100))

![]({{ site.baseurl }}/assets/images/sin_plot-1.png)
```

The liquid tag will be handled by Jekyll, but pandoc is getting in the way.

---

Issue opened with [rmarkdown](https://github.com/rstudio/rmarkdown/issues/1447)

Comment: I think you're approaching this the wrong way around. You should first replace the `{{variables}}`, then let pandoc run over it... see how e.g. [jekyll-pandoc](https://github.com/mfenner/jekyll-pandoc) does it...

Comment: i don't *want* to use pandoc at all, but it's baked in to `rmarkdown::render`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As noted in [the other answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52388191/687112), the "Knit" button calls `rmarkdown::render` and is unavoidably knitr + Pandoc. To give the RStudio users contributing to this blog a button to push, I moved everything to a simple Makefile.

```
RMD := $(shell find _posts/ -name '*.Rmd')
PORT = 4321
export GEM_HOME = ~/.gem

.PHONY: all

all: Gemfile.lock $(RMD:%.Rmd=%.md)
    bundle exec jekyll build --drafts --baseurl=/p/$(PORT)

Gemfile.lock:
    bundle install

%.md: %.Rmd
    Rscript --vanilla -e "knitr::knit('$<', '$@')"
```

For a live preview, the RStudio users can leave a `servr::httw('_site')` process running in their console and hit the "Build" button to update.

Answer (score 2):

Since you don't need Pandoc at all, you don't need to use **rmarkdown**, either. You can just use "vanilla" **knitr** (note that **rmarkdown** = **knitr** + Pandoc), i.e., `knitr::knit()` instead of `rmarkdown::render()`.

For Jekyll websites, **blogdown** may make your life a little easier since it supports Jekyll, too: https://bookdown.org/yihui/blogdown/jekyll.html You won't need to hit the `Knit` button but just `blogdown::serve_site()` and enjoy LiveReload. If you have never used **blogdown** before, you need to read at least Chapter 1 of the **blogdown** book (but ignore Hugo there).

Comment: In fact, I even recommend you to switch from Jekyll to Hugo, too.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, but then I'd also need Travis to build in the edits made via GitHub's editor to the .Md content. And my .ipynb bloggers would be sad.